# TSQL Cursor to include a row indicating a sort break

Tags: t-sql, cursor

I would like to create a "break" row when returning a dataset.  My Cobol program requires that I use a cursor.  The result set is ordered by CheckNumber, MemberID, & ClaimNo.  Each time the MemberID changes, I would like to return some row to indicate a break.

Eg,

```
Chk  MbrId  ClaimNo

100  PAUL   1-1
100  PAUL   2-2
100  XXXX  (break row)
100  SALLY  1-1
100  SALLY  2-2
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Provide us a code you've tried to use so you can get the result you want?

Comment: also let us know sql server version please

Comment: I'm having trouble grasping how your "Cobol program requires that I use a cursor." Can expound on that? I don't know COBOL, but a glance at https://supportline.microfocus.com/Documentation/books/sx40sp2/spcesc.htm didn't convince me.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion on cursor; I should have not put that in.  In Cobol when more than one row is returned, you need to access the data via a Cobol cursor. For the T-SQL I don't need a cursor.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that uses a derived table.  I don't know what version of SQL Server you are using, but it should be compatible back to at least SQL Server 2000.

```
--Test Table
CREATE TABLE #TestData (
    Chk INT,
    MbrId VARCHAR(16),
    ClaimNo VARCHAR(16)
)

--Test data.
INSERT INTO #TestData (Chk, MbrId, ClaimNo)
VALUES
    (100, 'PAUL', '1-1'),
    (100, 'PAUL', '2-2'),
    (100, 'SALLY', '1-1'),
    (100, 'SALLY', '2-2'),
    (100, 'JOHN', '1-1'),
    (100, 'JOHN', '2-2')

--Use this tsql statement for your cursor.
SELECT dt.Chk, dt.MbrTemp AS MbrId, dt.ClaimNo
FROM 
(
    SELECT Chk, MbrId, MbrId AS MbrTemp, ClaimNo, 1 SortOrder
    FROM #TestData
    UNION
    SELECT Chk, MbrId, 'XXXX' AS MbrTemp, '(break row)' ClaimNo, 2 SortOrder
    FROM #TestData
    GROUP BY Chk, MbrId
) dt    --derived table
ORDER BY Chk, dt.MbrId, SortOrder, ClaimNo
```

Comment: Nice because you don't actually use a cursor. ;-) You got a set based solution that can be used to power a cursor if necessary.